# how to get the last n row after order please

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DF like below:

```
val df = ss.sparkContext.parallelize( Seq (
  ("c1", "2017-1-1 00:00:00", 10, "A", "A,B"),
  ("c1", "2017-11-1 00:00:00", 10, "A", "A,B"),
  ("c1", "2017-5-1 00:00:00", 12, "B", "A,B"),
  ("c1", "2017-7-1 00:00:00", 13, "B", "A,B"),
  ("c2", "2017-3-1 00:00:00", 10, "B", "A,B"),
  ("c2", "2017-8-1 00:00:00", 11, "C", "A,B"),
  ("c2", "2017-5-1 00:00:00", 20, "C", "A,B"),
  ("c2", "2017-1-1 00:00:00", 18, "A", "A,B"),
  ("c2", "2017-9-1 00:00:00", 17, "A", "A,B")
)).toDF("city", "month", "sales", "area", "arealist")

val strToDate = udf( (str : String) => {
  val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd ");
  Timestamp.valueOf(str)
})
df.withColumn("month", strToDate($"month")).orderBy("city","month").show
```

The output is :

```
+----+-------------------+-----+----+--------+
|city|              month|sales|area|arealist|
+----+-------------------+-----+----+--------+
|  c1|2017-01-01 00:00:00|   10|   A|     A,B|
|  c1|2017-05-01 00:00:00|   12|   B|     A,B|
|  c1|2017-07-01 00:00:00|   13|   B|     A,B|
|  c1|2017-11-01 00:00:00|   10|   A|     A,B|
|  c2|2017-01-01 00:00:00|   18|   A|     A,B|
|  c2|2017-03-01 00:00:00|   10|   B|     A,B|
|  c2|2017-05-01 00:00:00|   20|   C|     A,B|
|  c2|2017-08-01 00:00:00|   11|   C|     A,B|
|  c2|2017-09-01 00:00:00|   17|   A|     A,B|
+----+-------------------+-----+----+--------+
```

I want to get the last 2 rows of "city".It looks like below:

```
+----+-------------------+-----+----+--------+
|  c1|2017-07-01 00:00:00|   13|   B|     A,B|
|  c1|2017-11-01 00:00:00|   10|   A|     A,B|
|  c2|2017-08-01 00:00:00|   11|   C|     A,B|
|  c2|2017-09-01 00:00:00|   17|   A|     A,B|
+----+-------------------+-----+----+--------+
```

how should I do please?

Comment: you don't need an `udf`, you can use `cast()` for date conversion: `df.withColumn("month", col("month").cast("date"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Window` functions to rank your observations per city, then keep only the ones with the latest month.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{rank,col}

val window = Window.partitionBy(df("city")).orderBy(df("month").desc)

df.withColumn("rank", rank().over(window))
  .filter(col("rank") <= 2) 
  .drop("rank")
  .show()
+----+----------+-----+----+--------+
|city|     month|sales|area|arealist|
+----+----------+-----+----+--------+
|  c1|2017-11-01|   10|   A|     A,B|
|  c1|2017-07-01|   13|   B|     A,B|
|  c2|2017-09-01|   17|   A|     A,B|
|  c2|2017-08-01|   11|   C|     A,B|
+----+----------+-----+----+--------+
```

Comment: is it `dense_rank().over(window)` ?